# JS - document.querySelector() || document.querySelector() gives type error

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code (dummy):

```
myFunction(document.querySelector('[data-param="param1"]').textContent || document.querySelector('[data-param="param2"]').textContent);
```

What is supposed to do is if `param1` exists, use that one, else, use `param2` by exploiting the use of `falsy`. I know this is not the best to use (see [here](http://www.codereadability.com/javascript-default-parameters-with-or-operator/)), but it is what I came up with for my circumstances.

I attempted to make a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4lackof/n3hL30me/) to demonstrate this; however, the error is wrong, although this could just be different wording in the consoles as I am using two different browsers (don't ask).

In Fire*bug* it says:

> TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null

and in Chrome it says:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'your-property-here' of null

I thought I had it working with `document.getElementById('param1') || document.getElementById('param2')` but what the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4lackof/n3hL30me/) is giving does not seem to work on either `querySelector` or `getElementById`.

I could not find anything about this on the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), and my google searching did not find anything...

**Is this a feature or a bug? Is there event a way to exploit `falsy` values on `querySelector` (or `getElementById1`, etc)? What would be the best way to go about doing what I want it to do?**

Comment: The code in your fiddle is very different: you're taking a property of `document.querySelector(something)`. Of course it can't work when there's no element.

Comment: @DenysSéguret whoops, fixed it Tku

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you see the error is because your first query is returning null, and thus it has no property dataset. Try this instead:

`(document.querySelector('[data-example="example1"]') || document.querySelector('[data-example="example2"]')).dataset.example`

Now if `document.querySelector('[data-example="example1"]')` is returning null, it will try `document.querySelector('[data-example="example2"]')` instead. You should be aware though, that if both queries return null you will still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

There is no bug in javascript regarding your case. It is a bug in your code. Because either `document.querySelector()` or `getElementById` would return `null` if the supplied parameter doesn't match any elements in the `document`. Hence `null.anything` would throws error. You could rewrite your code like below to avoid such errors,

```
var res = (document.getElementById('id1') || document.getElementById('id2')).id;
```

And here also, if both `id1` or `id2` doesn't match anything then the same error would be raised. You can handle that situation also like below,

```
var res = (document.getElementById('id1') || document.getElementById('id2') || {}).id;
```

Now in this case, if there is no match then `res` would be `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should correct the code as follows;

```
// data attribute:
var elm1 = document.querySelector('[data-example="example1"]') || document.querySelector('[data-example="example2"]');
    elm2 = document.getElementById('id1') || document.getElementById('id2');
document.getElementsByTagName('BUTTON')[0].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  try {

    e.target.className += elm1.dataset.example;
  } catch(e) {
    document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += '<div>' + e + new Date() + '</div>';
  }
});

// id:
document.getElementsByTagName('BUTTON')[1].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  try {
    e.target.className += elm2.id
  } catch(e) {
    document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += '<div>' + e + new Date() + '</div>';
  }
});
```